# Access a list of objects in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I think I'm missing something, but I'm trying to save to localStorage a list of objects, and then I want to display those objects.

When bringing the list, I print to the console and I get: *[object, Object]* so I use:

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

and started outputting: *"[object, Object]"*

So when displaying the list I get the error: obj.map is not a function.

It's wrong?

Code:

```
console.log(window.localStorage); // in console: Storage { "Lista-tareas": "[object Object],[object Object]", length: 1 }
let obj = window.localStorage.getItem("Lista-tareas");
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // in console: "[object Object],[object Object]"
console.log(obj.map( value => value.text )); // in console: error obj.map is not a function
```

Comment: When you stringify it it's not an object anymore. It's a string. To convert it back to an object you have to `JSON.parse(obj)` it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need [`JSON.parse(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), as what's stored in `localStorage` is already stringified:

```
try {
  // This line is just setting some test content inside localStorage:
  localStorage.setItem('someData', JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }));

  // This is how you get and parse a stringified object from localStorage:
  const someData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someData'));

  console.log(someData)
} catch(err) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find that function anywhere, now I can show my objects normally

Comment: @Gabo19 No problem. MDN or W3Schools are usually the best places to look first 

Comment: @Gabo19 Also, don't forget to upvote / accept if this resolved your issue 

Comment: @Danzinger Everything is resolved